# Show that if $ \ a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \ $, then $ \ \frac{a(a-1) \cdots (a-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ , p-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

**p-adic numbers:**

Consider the ring of p-adic integers $ \ \mathbb{Z}_p $.

Show that if $ \ a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \ $, then $ \ \frac{a(a-1) \cdots (a-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ also, where $n$ is natural number.

**Answer:**

To show that $\frac{a(a-1) \cdots (a-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, we have to show that $ \left|\frac{a(a-1) \cdots (a-n+1)}{n!} \right|_p \leq 1$.

I have seen some hintz in the book of "p-adic numbers, p-adic analysis and zet-function" of the autor "Neal Koblitz". The hintz is given below:

[image]

I did not understand how they have chosen $N$ and what does $ord_p(a-a_0)>N$ mean?

please help to understand this.

or

**Any other method to show that**  $ \ a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \Rightarrow \frac{a(a-1) \cdots (a-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ .

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the denominator $n!$, the point is that $a(a-1)...(a-n+1)/n!$ lives a priori in $\mathbf Q_p$, not necessarily in $\mathbf Z_p$. Whatever your construction of $\mathbf Z_p$ may be, you must think that an element $a\in \mathbf Z_p$, by definition, is"$p$-adically approximated" at any order $N$ by an $a_0 \in \mathbf Z$. This locution means that for any integer $N$, there exists $a_0 \in \mathbf Z$ s.t. $ord_p (a-a_0)>N$, which means in turn (by definition), that in $\mathbf Z_p$, you can write $a-a_o=up^M$, where $u\in \mathbf Z^*_p$ and $M>N$. Consequently, given $n$, the fraction $a(a-1)...(a-n+1)/n!\in \mathbf Q_p$ can be approximated at any order by $a_0(a_0-1)...(a_0-n+1)/n!$ (since $n$ is fixed, just take $N$ large enough). The latter fraction lives in $\mathbf Z$ because it expresses the number of combinations of $a_0$ objects among $n$, so the given fraction lives in $\mathbf Z_p$ .

EDIT: In case the final argument is not clear enough (see the OP query), I develop it in detail. For $N$ large enough, the two fractions (involving resp. $a$ and $a_0$) are $p$-adically close. But since the $p$-adic valuation is discrete, this means that the two fractions have the same $p$-adic absolute value, and we are done.

Comment: Oh ! I thought that the question was in the...question alone. But the extra-assertion comes for free as soon as we have shown that $\frac {a(a-1)...(a-n+1)}{n!}\in \mathbf Z_p$

Comment: No, there is no inaccuracy at all, I explained the details in my edit. The fraction involving $a_0$ lives in $\mathbf Z$, so the one involving $a$, which is $p$-adically close, lives in $\mathbf Z_p$.

Comment: No, you said combinations of $a$ objects among $n$, but when $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, it may not belong to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh! In the definition of the number of combinations of $a_0$ objects among $n$ ? OK, this was an obvious misprint (I edit it), I said right after: "the latter fraction", i.e. with $a_0$. I thought your objection was about the $p$-adic argument.

Comment: ok many thanks for your answer. It is a nice answer

Comment: Frankly I don't see the problem. If $a$ and $a_0$ are $p$-adically close,  the rational fractions $f(a)$ and $f(a_0 )$ are close because, by definition, the $p$-adic valuation is compatible with the field operations. If you want to speak of functions, $f: \mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf Q_p$ is continuous because of the reason invoked above, hence $f(a)$ is close to $f(a_0)$, and consequently lives in $\mathbf Z_p$. Note that the beginning of @egreg's answer is not quite correct: because of $n!$,$f$ is not a polynomial but a fraction, hence a priori $f$ is not a function $\mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p$.

Comment: sorry, I commented this for the answer given by $Rafay \ Asary$.  Your answer is perfect to me but before I could not understand the answer. Now I understood  your proof.

Comment: May I have an explanation for the downvoting of my answer of October 29 ?

Comment: No problem. After all, reputation points are just a kind of game. The important thing is the correctness or not of the answer.

Comment: Sir, can the fraction $ \frac{a(a-1) \cdots (a-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{Q}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}_p$ ? If so then under what condition?

Comment: For $a \in \mathbf Z_p$, no. The p-adic absolute value of n! can be quite *small*, see e.g. the formula on p.154 of Artin-Tate's "Class Field Theory", but the point in your original question is that you can approximate $a$ by $a_0 \in \mathbf Z$ at as high an order N as you want, thus the numerator will prevail.

Comment: which book you are mentioning ?

Comment: As I said, the classical book "Class Field Theory" by Artin & Tate.